# StartService returns access denied for SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER

Tags: c, winapi, 64-bit

This thing has given me a really bad headache.

I'm trying to load a driver into a process using `CreateService` and `SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS` everything appears to be fine until I actually try and start the service using `StartService` it always fails with the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` I'm running as administrator, I've baked a manifest into the app, I've tried the security attributes, it just wont work.

If anyone have any advice on how to debug this, I'm all ears...

I'm using a Windows 7 x64 SP1 installation, the latest DDK and if there was a problem with the driver itself I would get some other problem, right? not just, access denied?

Something I'm debating but having trouble testing is if there are any user-mode/kernel-mode security consideration that I'm not handling. All this code is running in the same elevated process, yet, it will not work!

Can the driver in some way cause this error to happen?

Comment: Your service isn't set to be disabled, is it?

Comment: I sure hope not, it's created using the SERVICE_DEMAND_START flag and according to the documentation and CurrentControlSet (services register key entry) it's load on demand (not disabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh the horror, I should have seen this earlier, anyway, the error code from a call done in the driver was being propagated through the create service call. This return value just happened to be the same as the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` but actually had to do with the driver not being properly signed.

This [page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/forced-integrity-signing-of-portable-executable-pe-files.aspx) explains what you need to do to be able to call certain functions within your driver.